# Julia What is The Fastest Way to Evaluate a Math Tree

Tags: performance, data-structures, julia

I have a tree of data representing a mathematical function, like this:
[image]

It is stored in arrays, so 2+3^2 would be represented as:

```
["+", 2, ["^2", 3] ]
```

To actually evaluate the tree, I have a recursive function

```
function evaluate(mathstructure::Array)
    if mathstructure[1] == "+"
        # do the operation
        evaluate(mathstructure[2]) + evaluate(mathstructure[3])
    elseif mathstructure[1] == "*"
        # do the operation
        evaluate(mathstructure[2]) * evaluate(mathstructure[3])
    elseif mathstructure[1] == "σ"
        # do the operation
        x = evaluate(mathstructure[2])
        1 / (1 + exp(-x))
    elseif mathstructure[1] == "^2"
        # do the operation
        x = evaluate(mathstructure[2])
        x^2
    end
end
function evaluate(mathstructure::Variable)
    mathstructure.value
end
```

(I actually have a `Variable` structure which has a value and an identifier to represent numbers, so I can change constants later)

This code works, but it is extremely slow. What steps should I take to optimize its performance? I can't use tail recursion because oftentimes the function calls its self twice.

Thank you!

-Diego

Comment: "This code works" + "optimize its performance" = [codereview.se]

Comment: @ForceBru No, it is on-topic. See: [Performance question - Stack Overflow or Code Review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300981/performance-question-stack-overflow-or-code-review) . This is one purpose of the `performance` tag (and a bit `optimization` too). However, the OP has to be quite precise and provide profiling information if possible (or a short reproducible example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tree representation is directly supported by the language so you can just write something like:

```
+(^(*(5,10),2),+(30,25))
```

This will be the fastest

However if you want a parser you could leverage the power of language and to this as a one liner.

I propose you the following representation of math tree having always 2 arguments:

```
dat = [:+,[:^,[:*, 5, 10],2], [:+, 30, 25]]
```

Than you can handle all with this one liner (should you have `String`s instead of `Symbol`s you could always do `Symbol(d[1])` in my code):

```
compu(d) = quote
    $(d[1])($(typeof(d[2])<:AbstractVector ? compu(d[2]) : d[2]), $(typeof(d[3])<:AbstractVector ? compu(d[3]) : d[3]))
end
```

Now lets test it:

```
julia> (+(^(*(5,10),2),+(30,25) ))
2555

julia> eval(compu(dat))
2555
```

Comment: This is a really elegant solution! I was hoping it would be possible to do something like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can get better performance if you make use of Julia's multiple dispatch, using tuples as your main type instead of heterogenous arrays.

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> evaluate(x::Number) = x
evaluate (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function evaluate(ex::Tuple{Symbol,Union{Tuple,Number}})
           (op, x_) = ex
           x = evaluate(x_)
           if op == :σ
               return 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
           elseif op == Symbol("^2")
               return x ^ 2
           else
               error("invalid unary operator $(op)")
           end
       end
evaluate (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> function evaluate(ex::Tuple{Symbol,Union{Number,Tuple},Union{Number,Tuple}})
           (op, x_, y_) = ex
           (x, y) = evaluate.((x_, y_))
           if op == :(+)
               return x + y
           elseif op == :(*)
               return x * y
           else
               error("invalid binary operation $(op)")
           end
       end
evaluate (generic function with 3 methods)

julia> evaluate((:+, 2, (Symbol("^2"), (:*, 4, (:σ, 9)))))
17.99605161718798

julia> 2 + (4 * 1/(1+exp(-9)))^2
17.99605161718798

julia> @benchmark evaluate((:+, 2, (Symbol("^2"), (:*, 4, (:σ, 9)))))
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 998 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  14.893 ns … 57.041 ns  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     14.947 ns              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   15.465 ns ±  2.190 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

  █   ▂    ▅                                                  ▁
  █▁█▃█▁▃▁▁█▅▄▄▄▃▁▁▁▁▁▃▁▁▁▁▃▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▃▄▅▅▇▆▆▆▆▆▆▆ █
  14.9 ns      Histogram: log(frequency) by time      25.6 ns <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Implementing this right now.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a frame challenge, but depending on your high-level goals you could consider not inventing your own expression system, but reuse something like [Symbolics.jl](https://github.com/JuliaSymbolics/Symbolics.jl).

Symbolic algebra packages usually have built-in support for expression simplification and "compilation" to native functions, such as Symbolics' [`build_function`](https://symbolics.juliasymbolics.org/stable/manual/build_function/) (which is more or less a fancy version of Przemyslaw's answer, but may result in much better optimized code if you expressions involve things like large arrays).