# How can I transform a mathematical expression into an easier-to-parse way, in Julia?

Tags: parsing, math, julia, expression, transform

Is there a predefined class or package in Julia that can handle this sort of transformation: x * (y - z) => [y, z, "-"; x, y, "*"] (this assumes that in the interest of saving memory space, the output of the first operation is stored in variable y before the second operation is applied).

Basically, I need to break down a mathematical expression into a series of steps which I can then apply to the variables involved, algorithmically.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can get an abstract syntax tree from an expression.
Since it is a Julian data structure you can than process or visualize it any way you want.

```
julia> dump(:(x * (y - z)))
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((3,))
    1: Symbol *
    2: Symbol x
    3: Expr
      head: Symbol call
      args: Array{Any}((3,))
        1: Symbol -
        2: Symbol y
        3: Symbol z
```

This mechanism is described in the [Metaprogramming section of Julia manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/)

Depending on what you actually need to do this question might be also related: [Julia What is The Fastest Way to Evaluate a Math Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73406555/julia-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-evaluate-a-math-tree/73410710#73410710)

Comment: Interesting. Not sure if I can apply this to custom-made operators though and variables taking the form of strings. E.g., can Julia handle an expression like ([1] % [4]) + ([1] + [2]) using the dump metaprogramming procedure? Thanks

Comment: @Zack Just write `ex = :(([1] % [4]) + ([1] + [2]))`. Then you can inspect `ex` with `ex.args`, etc. Or print the whole thing with `dump(ex)`, like before. Custom operators should be no problem, not sure what you mean by "variables taking the form of strings."

Comment: There is a shortcut for this answer if the code is available as a literal: `Meta.@dump (x * (y - z))`.